# matching patterns and replacement in R

Tags: r, replace, pattern-matching

I have two files.
One file (file1) is..

```
 Symbol pairs
1 ABAT  row1
2 ACADSB  row2
3 ACTG2  row3
4 ANXA3  row4
```

Another file (file2) is..

```
    rownames    Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
row1-row1    row1-row1  0   0   0
row1-row2    row1-row2  -1.819133494    0.3023401   -0.8904574
row1-row3    row1-row3  -3.409451405    0.1103111   -0.9247103
```

I want to replace "row1" with "ABAT", so ..

```
gsubr <- function(pattern, replacement, x) {
  for(i in 1:length(pattern))
    x <- gsub(pattern[i], replacement[i], x)
  x = as.data.frame(x) 
}
from = file1[,2]
to = file1[,1]

file2_rowname = gsubr(from, to, file2[,1])
```

But "file2_rowname" is weird. It included symbols absent in the file1's Symbol (eg. ABAT0, ABAT1, ABAT2..).

I want this result.

```
rownames Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
ABAT-ABAT 0 0 0
ABAT-ACADSB -1.819133494    0.3023401   -0.8904574
ABAT-ACTG2 -3.409451405 0.1103111   -0.9247103
```

Give me an advice. Thanks!!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Could you provide what you expect or want the result to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is split the `rownames`  according to `-` (with `strsplit`), replace the `row.` by the correct gene name (with `match`), according to the data.frame with the matches and finally "fuse" back the names (with `paste`), putting `-` in between the gene names.

So, in `R` language, this would be, if the data.frame with `rownames` is called `tab` and the data.frame with the matches is called `corresp`:

```
tab$rownames <-  sapply(lapply(strsplit(tab$rownames, "-"), 
                                 function(v){corresp$Symbol[match(v, corresp$pairs)]}), 
                          function(v){paste(v, collapse="-")})
tab
#     rownames   Sample1   Sample2    Sample3
#1   ABAT-ABAT  0.000000 0.0000000  0.0000000
#2 ABAT-ACADSB -1.819133 0.3023401 -0.8904574
#3  ABAT-ACTG2 -3.409451 0.1103111 -0.9247103
```

Is this the output you were looking for?

Comment: I got a message. Error in strsplit(tab$rownames, "-") : non-character argument

Comment: then try first `tab$rownames <- as.character(tab$rownames)` your variable is probably a factor